# Check if cache is active

Tags: 7, caching

I would like to set some functionality in a module only on if caching is turned off.

Is there a way to check in code if caching is on or off?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the regular "cache pages for anonymous users", but there can be many types of caching. Please specify.

Comment: I mean the check box "Cache pages for anonymous users" on /admin/config/development/performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Cache pages for anonymous users" setting is stored in the variable table (as a 0 or 1), you can get it like this:

```
if (variable_get('cache', 0)) {
  // Cache is turned on
}
```

If you're interested in the "Cache blocks" setting it's also in the variables table and you can get it like this:

```
if (variable_get('block_cache', 0)) {
  // Block cache is turned on
}
```

Just for reference the first is defined in [`system_performance_settings()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_performance_settings/7) and the second in [`block_form_system_performance_settings_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_form_system_performance_settings_alter/7).